How to integrate Splunk dashboard on my web app using SplunkUI tool?
who we are?
L Squared is a leading digital signage service provider, offering the Hub Content Management System (CMS). This platform empowers users to effortlessly manage and display media content on digital signage screens. we want render Splunk dashboard visualization on my web app using SplunkUI tool.
What we want?

Implementing OAuth 2.0 authentication for get access token or any other authentication method to get access token securely.

Providing users with a list of Splunk apps and their respective dashboards for selection.

Then Finally, render/embed Splunk dashboard visualization on my web app using SplunkUI tool.


What we have?

username and password of Splunk enterprise account for authorization.

generated JWT token though settings from Splunk enterprise account.

Get session Key from
E.g. curl -k -u admin:changeme  https://localhost:8089/services/auth/login -d username=admin -d password=changeme


demo dashboard created using Splunk enterprise account.



How to do?
To achieve these objectives, hub user will follow these steps:

Initiate an OAuth 2.0 authentication request to Splunk for access token generation or utilize client credentials such as username, password, JWT token, and session key.

Upon successful authorization, users gain access to Splunk REST API endpoints, including:

Retrieving a list of installed Splunk apps using the following API call:
e.g. "curl -k -u admin:password https://localhost:8089/services/apps/local?output_mode=json"


Fetching a list of dashboards for a specific Splunk app via the following API call:
e.g. curl -k -u admin:password https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/{username}/{app_name}/data/ui/views?output mode=json&search=((is Dashboard=1 AND (rootNode="dashboard") AND isVisible=1) AND ((eai:acl.sharing="user" AND eai:acl.owner="{username}") OR (eai:acl.sharing!="user")))




Finally, render/embed Splunk dashboard visualization on my web app using SplunkUI tool.


I have tried to get Splunk dashboard data UI view using Rest API Splunk Dashboard data UI view api.
https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/{username}/{app-name}/data/ui/views/{dashboard-name}

Expected: Render splunk dashboard UI view data into visualization in my web app.
